# Playing sounds on IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to play a sound when a button is pressed. I tried this:

```
-(void)PlayClick
{
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                           pathForResource:@"BubblePopv4"
                                           ofType:@"mp3"]];
AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
[click play];
}
```

…and imported `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>` and `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

but for some reason the sound is not playing. The name and type are right because the file I added to the project is "BubblePopv4.mp3". The volume on the iPad is on maximum, and the sound plays fine on iTunes! Any ideas?

Comment: by the way the code is called because I can see from NSLog

Comment: Is the iPhone put into silent (vibrator) mode ? If my memory is correct, AVAudioPlayer won't play if it is in this mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave it, Don't do it in a new Class, simple stuff for you:

```
- (void)playSoundWithOfThisFile:(NSString*)fileNameWithExtension {

    // Eg - abc.mp3
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayerObj;

    NSString *filePath;

    filePath= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]] retain];

    if(!audioPlayerObj)
        audioPlayerObj = [AVAudioPlayer alloc];

        NSURL *acutualFilePath= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",filePath,fileNameWithExtension]];

        NSError *error;

        [audioPlayerObj initWithContentsOfURL:acutualFilePath error:&error];

        [audioPlayerObj play];

}
```

Comment: and then [self playSoundWithOfThisFile]; ??

Comment: Yes [self playSoundWithOfThisFile:@"abcd.mp3"];

Comment: did it but it doesn't work!! the code does not give any errors apart from a bug in the [audioPlayerObj initWithContentsOfURL:acutualFilePath error:&error]; which is "expression results unused"

Comment: When NSLog(@"ha: %@", fileNameWithExtension); it gives: ha: BubblePopv4.mp3, which is right though

Comment: Did you write this line '[audioPlayerObj play];' ? your application is running under a Release mode?

Comment: My app uses ARC, and yes I kept the line [audioPlayerObj play]; in your code

Comment: This should work if there are no errors - Except your device is on mute?

Comment: no, my device is at full volume, all the audio of other apps work

Comment: there still is the bug "expression results unused"

Comment: Download this project - https://github.com/dcgrigsby/AudioPlayer and add your sound file and test it by changing this string "audiofile.mp3" to your file name.mp3 or something. Let me know if this works well for you.

Comment: Yes, the code from the project works fine in my app. Thanks!! Have you created the project?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

In .h file:

```
Use this delegate - <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayerObj;

NSString *filePath;
```

In .m file , In some method:

```
   filePath= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]] retain];

    if(!audioPlayerObj)
        audioPlayerObj = [AVAudioPlayer alloc];
```

And add these two methods:

```
- (id)initWithFileName:(NSString*)fileNameWithExtension {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        NSURL *acutualFilePath= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",filePath,fileNameWithExtension]];

        NSError *error;

        [audioPlayerObj initWithContentsOfURL:acutualFilePath error:&error];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)playSound {
    [audioPlayerObj play];
}
```

You can pass the filename to this Method - initWithFileName

and then call playSound method to play sound for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can I then call the contorller form my view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Replace url initialization with:

```
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                              pathForResource:@"BubblePopv4"
                                              ofType:@"mp3"]];
```

Comment: this gives me the error "no class method for selector 'initfileURLwithPath'

Comment: it is 'initFileURLWithPath' not 'initfileURLwithPath'