# Playing sounds with xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I looked for my answer but I didn't get the answer that I looked for. I want to play sounds on my iphone project. Which file types I can use? How it's codes gonna be? I don't know anything about that and I need your help? Thanks in advence...

Comment: What's the use case? Streaming? Just playing a file? Gaming sound effects? Do you need playback controls? What have you tried already? You need to give more information here.

Comment: I want to play a little mp3 file on an IBAction. @BergQuester

Comment: Which platform, iOS or Mac?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing sounds on IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303842/playing-sounds-on-ios)

Comment: http://bit.ly/1qZdYzS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in your ViewController.h, `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

Then in your ViewController.m:

```
@property SystemSoundID theSound;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Sound"
                                                    withExtension:@"mp3"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)(soundURL), &_theSound);
}

- (IBAction)playSound
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_theSound);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(_theSound);
}
```